# How to reset a value after 24 hour passed in android

Tags: java, android, timestamp

##### I want make a kind of a daily login reward.

I have a button named `ClaimReward` and A user can claim reward one time in a day!. if user claimed the reward then `disable` the `button` and if
24 hours passed then again `enabled` the `button`.

##### My try

```
I stored a today's date in firebase realtime database in millis (long) or timestamp - 1353534920
```

So, how can I do this in android

Answer (score 2):

You can get this output with this logic.

1. Store the value you want to reset to the preset value using shared preferences
2. Store the date-time value from the system using the sharedPrefs.
3. On App startup check if the local time matches the time in sharedPrefereces.

If it matches -> do nothing
if it does not -> reset

PS: Here shared preferences is just an example you can use room/datastore or anything to perform this check on app startup.